# what is the difference between interpreter and safe interpreter?

Tags: javascript, perl, scripting, tcl

Can anyone please explain me what exactly an interpreter .

Then what is meant by safe interpreter ?

I am new to TCL I am always confused about these words.

Comment: Did you checked this? https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/interp.htm

Answer (score 4):

A computer doesn't understand the text `alert("Hello, world!")` or `if (x == 5) return;`. They're part of a made up language, so you need some real executable computer code to either compile the text (transform it into real executable computer code) or interpret it (read it and run the appropriate computer instructions on-the-fly on behalf of the script).

One way to run a Perl script, for example, is to pass it's name as an argument to the `perl` program, and that program will interpret the text as a Perl script and "run" it for you. An interpreter isn't neccessarily an entire program; most JavaScript interpreters are just one part of a web browser, the IRC bot program eggdrop has a Tcl interpreter as a part of it, etc.

In Tcl, you can have multiple, independent scripts running, each one run by what's called an [interpreter](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/interp.htm). You create them with the `interp` command, and you can make them safe. A safe interpreter won't run any dangerous commands, like creating, opening or deleting files, so it's possible to e.g. let people run Tcl scripts on your computer via a web page.

An interpreter runs a script for you. You can call the executing code an interpreter, or the actual bytes of that code for an interpreter, or if a program contains only an interpreter and not much more, like `perl` or `tclsh`, I guess you can call that program an interpreter too.

Answer (score 4):

***Executive Summary:***
A safe interpreter is a context for running Tcl scripts that has been restricted so that the amount of damage that those scripts can do is extremely limited.

---

In general, a Tcl interpreter is a context for running Tcl scripts. You know the way Tcl uses global variables and has a whole bunch of global commands and procedures? They're all only global with respect to an interpreter context. All the other contexts in the process are unaffected by them. That's already quite a lot of isolation.

But Tcl goes further and allows interpreters to create child interpreters (sometimes called “slaves”, though I'm not too fond of that term). The parent interpreter (also “master”) can then poke special extra commands — cross-interpreter aliases — into the child interpreter to allow communication; the child just invokes a particular command with whatever arguments it wants to pass, and the parent decides what to do about it (if anything) and returns the result it wants to give. This is awesome as it allows you to expose an API without giving any hint about how it is implemented and with no way to break through; there are no backdoors. Child interpreters are only allowed to see those bits of their parents that the parents want them to.

Safe interpreters build on this, in that a safe interpreter is a child interpreter that was created in a special way (by passing the `-safe` option to `interp create`) which turns off and hides lots of default Tcl commands. The child interpreter can't `open` files, create `socket`s, `source` scripts, `load` extension code, or `exec` programs. (There's a few other things that are affected, but they're the main ones.) If the parent wants to expose the feature in a *limited* way, it can do via aliases (and, for doing `open` and `socket`, transferring ability to access an I/O channel). Tcl comes with some support for doing an extra profile of code on top of this — the [safe basic profile](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/safe.htm) — which enhances things to allow the child to do a `package require` of packages available to the parent *without* otherwise exposing any danger; it's up to the package whether it wants to work in a safe interpreter at all (many packages written in C may not, and Tcl packages might only work if they've got commands that are walled off).

There are a few limitations though. In particular, safe interpreters can still do types of local denial-of-service attacks through consuming far too much CPU or memory. There are [some mechanisms](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/interp.htm#M47) for dealing with the CPU issues in 8.5. However, memory is more awkward as Tcl doesn't tag memory allocations with the owning interpreter — that gets messy! Using really restrictive time limits may mitigate a lot of the trouble.

Tcl's safe interpreter features are based on [safe tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/software/plugin/safetcl.html) (that's a *really* old page, BTW; of historical interest) but without some of the funkier bits. In particular, writing policy profiles turned out to be very hard to do in general, but much easier in a totally app-specific way.